Weird build error on Keil µVision
I'm building a project based on modbus. The problem happens at the header file (.h). Even there are commas at the array, when I build, it gives error as [expected a ","]. I couldn't find out the reason behind. Hope you can help me the find it. When I comment all 0bxxxxxxxx values, the errors disappear for some reason that I don't understand.
Complete error message:

../Core/Inc/modbusSlave.h(42): error:  #253: expected a ","

But this error repeats for each row of array.
This is the problematic array:
static const uint8_t Inputs_Database[25] = {
    0b01001001, 0b10011100, 0b10101010, 0b01010101, 0b11001100,
    0b10100011, 0b01100110, 0b10101111, 0b01100000, 0b10111100,
    0b11001100, 0b01101100, 0b01010011, 0b11111111, 0b00000000,
    0b01010101, 0b00111100, 0b00001111, 0b11110000, 0b10001111,
    0b01010100, 0b10011001, 0b11111000, 0b00001101, 0b00101010
};

Although it gave errors, this array doesn't give error even it is at the same .h file.
This is the working array:
static uint16_t Holding_Registers_Database[50] = {
    0,  1111,  2222,  3333,  4444,  5555,  6666,  7777,  8888,  9999,   // 0-9   40001-40010
    12345, 15432, 15535, 10234, 19876, 13579, 10293, 19827, 13456, 14567,  // 10-19 40011-40020
    21345, 22345, 24567, 25678, 26789, 24680, 20394, 29384, 26937, 27654,  // 20-29 40021-40030
    31245, 31456, 34567, 35678, 36789, 37890, 30948, 34958, 35867, 36092,  // 30-39 40031-40040
    45678, 46789, 47890, 41235, 42356, 43567, 40596, 49586, 48765, 41029,  // 40-49 40041-40050
};


i think the last element of the second array has a comma after it, or i see it alone.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66281737/assigning-a-variable-using-binary-format-0b-causing-error-in-arm-keil-uvision

I believe your issue is that 0b01001001 is not a C standard constant. It's a GCC extension.
uVision uses one of the ARM compilers AFAIK. As a result, it is getting confused because it is seeing an invalid character (b) where it would otherwise expect a comma between numbers.
Change all of the 0b01001001 etc. to their equivalent decimal (73) or hexadecimal (0x49) values.

Refer to this StackOverflow question for more details.
